# How can I synchronize an Ubuntu Server with an email-account via SyncMl/ ActiveSync?

Tags: server, sync, email, evolution

To clarify my question:

I have an Ubuntu Server, and an email-account on (at/with?) a webmail provider using Horde as their system. So they offer synchronization via SyncMl and ActiveSync.

Now I want to synchronize calendar,tasks and the like with my Ubuntu-Server the same way I have synced my phone with the mail provider (where I used the Android standard Exchange ActiveSync).

I dont just want to view these on my server, i'd like a real copy. The basic idea behind all this is, I have a foswiki running on the ubuntu-server and I would like to have full synchronization between foswiki (so my server), my mail account and my phone. So if I'm creating a new calendar entry or task on my phone, I also have them in foswiki. It should also be usable with more users/ mail-accounts (all at the same provider).

Are there any ways tho accomplish this, preferably without getting to complicated or requiring advanced programming knowledge?

I'm also completely open do different solutions or ideas so feel free to correct my weird planned thing.

Thanks in advance for everybody who takes the time to read and think about my question.

PS: I'm just an inexperienced student trainee in my first undergrad year, so please don't be to hard on me :).